# Rails Trying to submit a form onchange of dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, submit

I have my Ajax working, builtin Rails javascript, with the submit button.  However, I would like it to submit when I change the value of the dropdown box and eliminate the button.  In my research I found what looks like the correct solution but I get no request to the server.  Here is my dropdown form code, note it still has the submit button that worked before I added :onchange:

```
<% form_tag('switch_car', :method => :put, :remote => true) do %>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Car Name:</label>
    <%= select_tag(:id, options_from_collection_for_select(active_cars, "id", "name"), 
       :onchange => ("$('switch_car').submit()"))%><%= submit_tag "Switch Car" %>
  </div>    
<% end %>
```

Here is the HTML generated:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="switch_car" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="PEbdqAoiik37lcoP4+v+dakpYxdpMkSm7Ub8eZpdF9I=" />
  </div>
  <div class="field"> 
    <label>Car Name:</label> 
    <select id="id" name="id" onchange="$('switch_car').submit()">
      <option value="9">Truck</option>
      <option value="10">Car</option>
    </select>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Switch Car" /> 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What JavaScript library are you using? Your :onchange has Ruby code, it should be a JavaScript call.

Comment: @MauricioLinhares I am using the libraries that install with Ruby on Rails 3.  So I need to figure out how to submit the form through javascript?

Comment: Sorry, @MauricioLinhares I see what you are saying.  I am now trying to get rails to do it with a remote_function but am still having no luck.  I would think this is fairly common though I am having difficulty finding a solution.  I just want to submit the form on select?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I was able to do to get it to work.  I named the form switch_car by using :name => "switch_car" and used the following javascript.

```
:onchange => ("javascript: document.switch_car.submit();")
```

I am still looking for a better answer so I will updated if I find something.  This doesn't use submit .js for some reason.  It processes it as HTML unlike the submit button which uses AJAX to update only the changing page elements.  But this is the best I have been able to find so far.

Answer (score 23):

Replace your onchange with this,

```
onchange: "this.form.submit();"
```

Comment: This will not trigger ajax when using `rails-ujs`. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 21):

`this.form.submit()` will not work if form is `remote: true` and `rails-ujs` is in use. In that case, a regular submit will occur instead of XHR.

Instead you should:

```
onchange: 'Rails.fire(this.form, "submit")'
```

You can read [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546) for more details.

Comment: And in Rails 6 Rails isn't exposed anymore... My hair is turning gray over everything constantly deprecating.

Comment: To keep it exposed, open your _app/javascript/packs/application.js_ and put it back under global e.g. `import Rails from '@rails/ujs'; global.Rails = Rails;`.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but none of the above answers work for me. They all result in a text/html request.

The following works, e.g. (the hide class sets css display: none):

```
<%= form.radio_button :tier_id, tier.id, onchange: "$('#submit-button-id').click();" %>
```

together with:

```
<%= form.submit "Save changes", id: 'submit-button-id', class: 'hide' %>
```

Comment: I will say with a submit_tag you can set the hidden param to be true like "hidden: true" and it will hide the button. This works Rails 6

Comment: This is a quick and obvious way to solve the issue that I had overlooked.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the js library you are using:

Prototype: `:onchange => ("$('switch_car').submit()")`

Jquery: `:onchange => ("$('#switch_car').submit()")`

If you are using the defaults and your rails version is below 3.1, then prototype is the default library.

Comment: Thanks.  I have version 3.0.9 so I tried the first option.  When I make the change in the select box no request is sent to the server.  I updated code above.  Any idea where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: still no luck with this.  Can't figure out why it doesn't send a request to the server?

Comment: install firebug(firefox plugin) to debug, and try executing the javascript manually on firebug console to see if it works, or what the problem is.

Comment: I use chrome and when I have the javascript console open I can see that nothing happens when I use the prototype code you suggested above.  If I put in the javascript: code in from above it works but doesn't do ajax.  It responds with a full html refresh.

Answer (score 3):

A more general solution using jQuery (I don't need to know the name of the form) is:

```
onchange: "$(this).parent('form').submit();"
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been around for a while but, I'll post my findings anyway since I haven't found this explanation anywhere yet.

I came across this [article](http://5minutenpause.com/blog/2014/03/28/submit-remote-forms-with-jquery-in-rails/) which describes quite well what's the problem when triggering a ajax request via the `submit()` method (with or without jQuery or Handler). The author then recommends to form your own AJAX request. That is not required and shouldn't be done to make use of the logic within [rails.js](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) (jquery-jus gem).

Problems with triggering `submit()` manually occur since rails.js binds and listens to an event that is namespaced `submit.rails`. To manually trigger a submission use

```
   onchange: 'javascript: $( this ).trigger("submit.rails")'
```

on the element or the form.

Answer (score 1):

For a select_tag, just add:

```
{:onchange => "myHandler();" }
```

where your handler will be:

```
this.form.submit();
```

Also, if onchange doesn't work you might want to try onChage with a capital C.

Finally, make sure NOT TO CONFUSE a select_tag with a form select.

See my answer to a similar question, only regarding a form select

[Adding An Onchange Event To A Form Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690516/select-and-onchange-in-a-ruby-on-rails-form/26127746#26127746)

Comment: Sorry, but you are messing up `select` with `select_tag`. The signature of `select_tag` is here: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag and there is only **one** options parameter. Your code example is actually producing an error.

Comment: Thanks Martin you are correct, I will make a distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Time at 2021, with Rails 6

make a hidden submit then use js `click()` function:

```
<%= form_with(modle: @user, local: false) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :menu1, ["option1","option2"], {}, onchange: "javascript:this.form.commit.click();" %>
    <%= f.submit 'save', class: "hidden" %>
<% end>
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8690633/15461540

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn rails way ajax submit on fields change here is the code.

```
<%= select_tag(:id, options_from_collection_for_select(active_cars, "id", "name"), 
data: { remote: true, url: your_ajax_route_path }%><%= submit_tag "Switch Car" %>
```

> data: { remote: true, url: your_ajax_route_path }

will automatically submit your input to your_ajax_route_path. If you are using a form builder then you should use with input_html

```
input_html: { data: { remote: true, url: your_ajax_route_path } }
```

like this. I hope it'll be useful for you

Comment: Why do you need <%= submit_tag "Switch Car" %> if the submission happens on change?

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions was working for me so I used the given below solution.

```js
$("#q_dimension_id_eq").on("change", function (e) {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rails 4.2.1 with `jquery_ujs` and it works for me:

`onchange: 'jQuery(this).parent().trigger("submit")'`

OBS.: It assumes the element is immediately child from form. You must adjust `parent()` according your DOM tree.