# How can I change the status of what I selected in the dropdown to True on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 <%= f.select :tag_id, options_from_collection_for_select(RfidTag.all.where('status = ?','f'), :tag_id, :tag_id) %>
```

This is the code I use to make a dropdown that has all the id's of the tags I have entered into the data base which have the status set to false by default. How can I fix the above code so that If I choose a tag, the tag is selected and it's status is changed to true.

Comment: just posted the code sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

In `options_from_collection_for_select` you can specify what should be already selected with the fourth argument. Just include there the `tag_id` of the current record.

```
options_from_collection_for_select(RfidTag.all.where('status = ?','f'), :tag_id, :tag_id, f.object.tag_id ) %>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to post to the endpoint `rfidtags/:id` with the params `{status: true}`, this will update your `rfidtag` with the provided id.

If you want this to work when a result is selected from the dropdown, instead of hitting a submit button, you will have to use some js. This answer might help you with that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961920/1079609

Comment: won't I have to change something in the controller? like the update method?

Comment: If you used rails generators the controller default update method should work without further changes.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by  "post to the endpoint rfidtags/:id with the params {status: true}"?

Comment: If you [scaffolded](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) your controller, you should have an edit page for each rfidtags. That page should be under  `rfidtags/:id/edit`. This